# How is Bramhana part of Veda?

Tags: scripture, vedas, brahmanas

Bramhana (like Aitareya brAhmana, satapata Bramhana, etc) are said to be part of Vedas and seem to expound the meaning of Samhita mantra and how to do Yajna. They also contain many legends like story of Yajnavalkya, Ajatshatru, Janaka etc.

On the other hand Veda are said to be timeless and not creation of any human.

So how can Bramhana be part of Veda/Shruti when they contain stories of real people?

In this aspect they seem similar to Smritis like Ramayan, Mahabharata etc.

Comment: Are you asking for Bramhanas like Aitareya brAhmana, satapata Bramhana, etc, (or) BRAHMAN , the formless God (or) brAhmins? Your question is not clear please

Comment: ब्राह्मण यथा शतपथ ब्राह्मण

Comment: Please use English language.  Most of the members may not be aware of either Sanskrit or Hindi

Comment: I have edited the question. There should be no confusion now.

Comment: Even the Veda contain mention of Bharata, Manu,  Daraajanya war, Agasthya and Lopamudra,etc. The veda  contain prayers for progeny.   So containing stories of real people in brAhmanas doesn't make them separate from the Veda. There are other issues ,which are being put forth by scholars , for claiming that the veda and brAhmanas do not for a group @Lokesh

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Mention of Bharata, Manu etc is understandable as long as they relate with the vidhi of yajna and other rituals, but their mention doesn't seem justifiable given Brahamana are not for telling history but instead for telling `1. vidhi, rules or directions for [sacrificial] rites [and] 2. artha-vāda, explanatory remarks'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the answer provided by **[Sri Kiron Krishnan](https://qr.ae/pNvgbH)** in another site, on the same subject.

> Actually, if ***Vedas refer to the revealed, inspired visions of the
>   sages***, then they comprise undoubtedly of only the poetic saṃhitās of
>   the kavis, also called Ṛṣis. The rest of the prose don’t have any
>   metrical constraint, they can vary to any limit, and are works
>   illustrating the use of these verses in some rituals, or speculations
>   related. Only the Ṛks, sāmans having chandases and Yajus formulas
>   comprise of the revealed vision. Rest are human constructs over it,
>   having little to do with the sages or their vision.
>
> But, people. Their beliefs.
>
> Pūrva mīmāṃsakas largely believe that Vedas were revealed only for the
>   purpose of yajñas because that is what is said by Brahmanas and Pūrva
>   mīmāṃsaka scriptures. Thus, the verses of Vedas cannot have any
>   independent existence other than the rituals to which they are
>   applied. And this also makes them consider both mantras and brāhmaṇas
>   as Vedas.
>
> Uttara mīmāṃsakas are clever, for they have already planned great
>   philosophies from easily accessible Upanishads and are too illiterate
>   or too impatient or too contemptuous to learn or even check Vedas and
>   Brahmanas, so they consider Upanishads as Vedas too, though many of
>   these Upanishads are not even composed in Vedic language, and have
>   nothing to do in content with Vedas.
>
> Medieval Hindus tried to make Itihāsas or sometimes even Puranas as
>   fifth Veda too, for they loved stories and were so reluctant to even
>   spend some effort to study Vedas or what they are.
>
> Then came Arya samaj. Dayanand considered only saṃhitās as Vedas, but
>   also honoured Manu smṛti, and believed in karma and rebirth, for
>   reasons only he knows.
>
> Then come our great Hare Kṛṣṇas. For them, saṃhitās are already out of
>   syllabus. Instead, they have two Vedas - Bhagavad Gītā (as it is) and
>   Śrīmad Bhāgavatam. (translated by ISKCON) And they put up great sites
>   having “Vedas” “Vedic” in names, and you will see nothing but SB and
>   BG in them.
>
> The idea about what Vedas are, among people, generally decreases in
>   the order :
>
> Pūrva mīmāṃsakas > Arya samaj > Uttara mīmāṃsakas ~ Medieval Hindus >
>   ISKCON.

Comment: The first paragraph makes sense because in the Purusha Suktam it is said that only, rik, sam and yajus were created at the time of creation. Someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Who is Sri Kiron Krishnan? Is he an Acharya or Guru?

Comment: You can check his profile in Quora

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Read [copy-paste issue](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/277). We are not here to reproduce the same text from one QA site to another. You should write in your own words, citing authentic sources. (Although you may mention the credit to quora but it doesn't mean we should just copy-paste from Quora)